# How to go about logging in GKE without using Stackdriver

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We are unable to grab logs from our GKE cluster running containers if StackDriver is disabled on GCP. I understand that it is proxying stderr/stdout but it seems rather heavy handed to block these outputs when Stackdriver is disabled.

How does one get an ELF stack going on GKE without being billed for StackDriver aka disabling it entirely? or is it so much a part of GKE that this is not doable?

From the article linked on a similar question regarding GCP:

"Kubernetes doesn’t specify a logging agent, but two optional logging agents are packaged with the Kubernetes release: Stackdriver Logging for use with Google Cloud Platform, and Elasticsearch. You can find more information and instructions in the dedicated documents. Both use fluentd with custom configuration as an agent on the node." (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#exposing-logs-directly-from-the-application)

Perhaps our understanding of Stackdriver billing is wrong?

But we don't want to be billed for Stackdriver as the 150MB of logs outside of the GCP metrics is not going to be enough and we have some expertise in setting up ELF for logging that we'd like to use.

Comment: welp, guess we are going to AWS. GCP support failed and I tried carrying the GCP torch but got let down.

Comment: Are you using Elasticsearch as the alternative to Stackdriver or are you adding a logging agent sidecar for your pods?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable Stackdriver logging/monitoring on Kubernetes by editing your cluster, and setting "Stackdriver Logging" and "Stackdriver Monitoring" to disable.

I would still suggest sticking to GCP over AWS as you get the whole Kube as a service experience. Amazon's solution is still a little way off, and they are planning charging for the service in addition to the EC2 node prices (Last I heard).

Comment: That's half way there. Once disabled, we found that stderr/stdout was unable to be read from any logging things we created.

Comment: That's strange, can you get logs by running **kubectl logs _podname_**?
I've had some luck with fluentd on GKE

Comment: not sure. All I saw was that the EFK stack was consuming logs when StackDriver was enabled but we were under the impression that we were being billed. When StackDriver is disabled no logs were being consumed. After researching I saw the bit about stderr/stdout being proxied by StackDriver using an agent